# Advice about simple architecture with a timer

Tags: ios, properties

This problem seems like it should be simple but I can't wrap my head around it. I have a Core Data store that contains 'games'. These games have an attribute to store time for a timer: game.timer. All that is fine.

I also have a centralized timer in my App Delegate that posts notifications as it ticks so various view controllers can display that time. All of that is fine.

Here's the simple thing I'm stuck on. The view controller that the user starts/stops the timer from and displays the ticking time, in viewWillLoad it grabs the time in game.timer and sets the time property in the app delegate for the centralized timer. And when the timer runs, the label in the view gets updated. That all works fine.

But when that view is first shown I don't know how to display the static amount of time in the label. So as an example, if I did it in viewWillLoad the timer would show 20:00. Great. And if I start the timer that label will tick down. Also great. But if I leave the view and return the label will be set to 20:00 again (and tick down from there assuming the timer is still running.)

So I need to track state somehow about setting the initial time in the label. Make sense?

EDIT: My timer counts down. I need to show the starting time, say 20:00, when the view first loads. If the timer is running that label will get updated properly. But if I leave the view and I come back I don't want the label to revert to 20:00 if the timer is running.

Comment: You probably need to post some code.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I just added a bunch of state to check if the timer has been set and whatnot. Not as elegant as I'd like but it'll work.